# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = n^3}^{(n+1)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2 +4k}}$

Tags: limits, summation

I stumbled upon the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = n^3}^{(n+1)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2 +4k}}$$
I've been trying to solve it but I'm completely stumped and there is no provided solution, by numerical computation it appears to approach $3$ but I have no mathematical proof.

Comment: Hint: $$
((n + 1)^3  - n^3 +1)f((n + 1)^3 ) < \sum\limits_{k = n^3 }^{(n + 1)^3 } {f(k)}  < ((n + 1)^3  - n^3 +1)f(n^3 )
$$ and use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $$S(n):= \sum\limits_{k = n^3 }^{(n + 1)^3 } {f(k)}$$
I shall follow Gary's hint; but provide more details. Consider $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$f(k) = \frac{1}{(k^2 + 4k)^{1/3}}$$
Note that $f$ is strictly decreasing, i.e., $f(n) > f(n+1)$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$. With that in mind, we have
$$((n + 1)^3  - n^3 + 1)f((n + 1)^3 ) < S(n)  < ((n + 1)^3  - n^3 + 1)f(n^3)$$
which is nothing but
$$\frac{3n^2 + 3n+ 2}{((n+1)^6 + 4(n+1)^3)^{1/3}} < S(n) < \frac{3n^2 + 3n+ 2}{(n^6 + 4n^3)^{1/3}}$$
Taking $n\to\infty$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3n^2 + 3n+ 2}{((n+1)^6 + 4(n+1)^3)^{1/3}} \le \lim_{n\to\infty} S(n) \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3n^2 + 3n+ 2}{(n^6 + 4n^3)^{1/3}}$$
giving
$$3 \le \lim_{n\to\infty} S(n) \le 3$$
so that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} S(n) = 3$$

Comment: The number of terms in $\sum_a^b$ is $b-a+1$ and not $b-a$.

Comment: @Gary Minor glitch! Thanks for pointing out. Edited.

Comment: Also, it seems that you use $S$ for the sum (which depends on $n$ btw) and for its limit at the same time.